# Clustering similar texts using Affinity Propagation and creating a cluster plot

Tags: python, string, text, cluster-analysis

I have a list of universities to be clustered based on similarity. For example, this string "University of Melbourne" and this string "University of Meelbourne" is the same, but has a spelling error.

I would like to group these similar strings together using Affinity Propagation (Scikit Learn) technique. Do I need to transform the Strings first, using Word2VEC before applying Affinity Propagation on SciKit learn ?

Is there a good tutorial which could show me how to accomplish this?

Comment: I suggest you to perform pre processing before applying clustering algorithms. like stop words, stemming, lemmatization etc.,

Comment: Is there a good method (maybe using a particular Python library) to group all similar occurring University names together, based on the list I have ?

Comment: I think there is no such python lib. but you could try to find text similarity between text after pre processing will simplify your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't abuse clustering for spelling correction!

### Word2vec will not work.

It won't have "Meelbourne" in it's vocabulary, because it is a rare spelling mistake. So it will ignore this word! For BOW approaches, it is also not helpful.

This just is not a problem that clustering can solve. Use a spell corrector instead.